# 100% Screen Size Regardless of Resolution

Tags: javascript, css, html, fullscreen

I'm attempting to make a website in which the user navigates vertically between a series of sections.  Basically each section takes up the whole screen, regardless of screen resolution, and has a button on the bottom that will scroll down to the next, full screen div.  any idea on how to approach this? the buttons seem like simple enough java script but i'm not quite sure how to approach the full screen divs

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an approach, you're going to want to only show on div at a time, so you might want to look at how various JS slider plugins work (one of the most robust and flexible is Flexslider by WooThemes).

You'll want to make sure that whatever "slide" is currently visible has a fixed position that occupies the full screen:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And then just put your content in there. That said, I do question the usability of an approach like this.

Comment: thanks for the help! i'll give this a shot.  
it was a request by my boss

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` div that contains all the displayable html for a site takes up the whole screen.

By setting a div's `height` and `width` to 100%, you can ensure that it takes up the entirety of its containing div.

Using the height and width properties and setting them to percentages, you can create divs and content that take up an entire screen, no matter what its size.

You can use [this tool](https://quirktools.com/screenfly/) to see how your site looks on different desktop, tablet, and mobile screens.

Comment: `height: 100%` doesn't always work. The value is only relative to the parent container.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi right, I believe I covered that in the second line "By setting a div's height and width to 100%, you can ensure that it takes up the entirety of its containing div"

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi I do think though that in order for percentage `width` and `height` settings to work, the parent div has to have a `position` value of `relative`

Comment: Sorry mate, somehow missed that last bit. I'm still not sure the 100% height setting is predictable enough for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about full screen window, not sure about it. But if you are talking about occupying the complete browser width and height then must try

1. Make these sections position absolute
2. Align them to Top=0 and left= 0 with 100% width and height
3. Just let the button on every section know how to show the next section and hide the current one.

   - Make sure that no parent elements of these sections be positioned relative else this will fail.

> ```
>  <div id="container">
>     <div id="section1">Section1Content <button id="btnSec-1"></button></div>
>     <div id="section2">Section1Content <button id="btnSec-2"></button></div>
>     <div id="section3">Section1Content <button id="btnSec-3"></button></div>4
>     </div>
> ```

Your css:

> ## section1,#section2,#section3{position:absolute;top:0;left:0; width:100%;height:100%;}

Your Jquery Script

> $("[id*=btnSec]").on("click", function(e){
>       var sec = $(this).attr("id").split("btnSec-")[1];
>       var nextSec = Number(sec)+1;
>       $("#container").children().hide();
>       $("#section"+nextSec).show();
>       })